# R - how to replace values in a subset of a vector

Tags: r, vector, replace, subset, readline

I have a bash script that is basically a series of commands to download a bunch of climate files. Among many other information on the script, lines 28 to 1027 determine the actual files that should be downloaded. See my file:

```
# point to file
file <- 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/27700634/wget-ESG-files.sh'

# read file content
r.lines <- readLines(con=file)
```

What I need to do is:

1) detect a pattern in the name of the files, subsetting only the files I really need to download. I can do this, see the code:

```
# choose variable name. 
# in this case, average monthly precipitation
var <- 'pr_Amon'

# find only the lines that contain my variable of interest 
new.r.lines <- r.lines[grepl(var, r.lines)]
new.r.lines
```

2) now, what I need to do is replace all the contents of elements 28 to 1027 of the original file by the contents of the variable "new.r.lines". The result must be a vector as well, because by the end of the script I will use writeLines to create a new file.

This is probably a very easy task, but I'm just stuck in this step.

Any help is much appreciated!

Thanks,
Thiago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build the new set of file lines as follows:

```
new.r.lines <- c(r.lines[1:27],r.lines[28:1027][grepl(var,r.lines[28:1027])],r.lines[1028:length(r.lines)]);
```

This combines lines 1:27 with the subset of the following 28:1027 lines that match your search pattern, then further combines with lines 1028 to the end of the file. Thus, you can pass that to `writeLines()` to create the new file.

Here's a slightly more concise approach that builds an index vector and then indexes the line vector once:

```
new.r.lines <- r.lines[c(1:27,27+grep(var,r.lines[28:1027]),1028:length(r.lines))];
```

Comment: Many thanks @bgoldst. I can't imagine a better idea!